# I need to clone a list

Tags: c#, list, clone

I have a list originalDailyDetailReport that I need to clone. The data in it will be changed during the application, but when I'm printing the final reports, I do need the original data.

I though this bit of code should do the trick, but in the end, my duplicateDailyDetailReport list, that I only use to print the reports, is changed.

Any ideas?

```
    public DailyDetailReports SaveOriginalDailyDetailReportData(DailyDetailReports originalDailyDetailReport )
            {
                DailyDetailReports duplicateDailyDetailReport = new DailyDetailReports();

                try
                {
                    duplicateDailyDetailReport.Rec.AddRange(
originalDailyDetailReport.Rec.ConvertAll<Receivables>(rec => rec));

    duplicateDailyDetailReport.Dil.AddRange(
originalDailyDetailReport.Dil.ConvertAll<Dilution>(dil=> dil));

    duplicateDailyDetailReport.Acc.AddRange(
originalDailyDetailReport.Acc.ConvertAll<Accountable>(acc => acc));
                                duplicateDailyDetailReport.Out.AddRange(
originalDailyDetailReport.Out.ConvertAll<Outstanding>(o => o));
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                                }

                                return duplicateDailyDetailReport ;
                            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it myself. I used reflection.

Here's the code. Good or bad, it works.

```
public static DailyDetailReports CloneLists(DailyDetailReports listToClone)
        {
            DailyDetailReports clonedList = new DailyDetailReports();

            clonedList.Rec.AddRange(PerformTheCloning(listToClone.Rec));
            clonedList.Dil.AddRange(PerformTheCloning(listToClone.Dil));
            clonedList.Acc.AddRange(PerformTheCloning(listToClone.Acc));
            clonedList.Out.AddRange(PerformTheCloning(listToClone.Out));

            return clonedList;
        }

    public static List<T> ListCloning<T>(List<T> listToClone)
            {
                PropertyInfo[] listToCloneProperties = listToClone.GetType().GetGenericArguments().First().GetProperties();

                try
                {
                    List<T> clonedList = new List<T>();

                    foreach (object t in (IEnumerable<object>)listToClone)
                    {
                        object clonedListRecord = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), null);

                        foreach (PropertyInfo t1 in listToCloneProperties)
                        {
                            PropertyInfo clonedListProperty =
                                clonedListRecord.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(record=> record.Name == t1.Name);

                            if (clonedListProperty != null)
                                clonedListProperty.SetValue(clonedListRecord, t1.GetValue(t, null), null);
                        }

                        clonedList.Add((T)clonedListRecord);
                    }

                    return clonedList;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }

                return null;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following, clone each item and create a new list.

```
var newList = yourlist.Select(r => r.Clone()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the original list, make a copy of **each element** (a copy of it's instance, not just copy of reference), and add that copy into new list.

Answer (score 0):

A list is made up of references to individual objects not the actual objects. When you copy the list, a new list is created that references the same objects as the old one. You'll have to deep-copy the objects field by field and push those on the list.